# Parse Server PHP user query

Tags: parse-platform

I have a customer who has an app with Heroku + Parse Server.

Now he wants a website.

Is the first time I use Parse Server and I have a problem.

For users he has a column like this:

```
    Id        Fruits
   ----      --------
    12        apple
    13        apple,orange
    14        lemon,orange
    15        banana,apple
              ...
```

To get users with `apple` in SQL only need make a query with `LIKE '%apple'`.
With Parse Server I see on documentation equalTo, containsAll, containedIn...

```
 $query->startsWith("fruits", "apple");
 $query->containsAll("areas", ['laboral']);
```

but I not beable to get all users with 'apple'.
Only the users that starts with 'apple' (id 12 and id 13, but no id 15) or users with 'only apple' (in the example, user id 12).

But I need get ids 12, 13 and 15.

**How can I do this?**

Thank you!!

Comment: what is "areas" ? You realise that you are trying to query on something that does not exist right? Try this `$query->containsAll("fruits", ["apple"]);`

Comment: Really areas is the field's real name. Fruits was an example, but I forgot to change it in this case.

I need searching lawyer areas, not fruits. I hope I have been clear right now.

Comment: With `$query->containsAll("fruits", ["apple"]);` only get id 12. 
I tryed it.

Comment: "Fruits" is an array or string?

Comment: Fruits are string

Comment: It should be an array then so you can use `containsAll` and solve your issue :)